# Redirecting to homepage when trying to access the WordPress' sub-directory

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I've installed WordPress on a sub-directory (like this: http://example.com/wp/) and used this method to make the website not appear in the sub-directory: 
https://websavers.ca/make-wordpress-not-appear-like-subfolder

It works perfectly, but now I want to create a redirect from the sub-directory /wp to the homepage. Right now, when I navigate to http://example.com/wp/ I get a 404 error page.
My goal is, when someone tries to access http://example.com/wp/ he will be redirected to http://example.com/

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

It's better not to use these sort of subdomain redirect rules within WordPress:

1. WordPress may not load properly when you access it using the wrong domain name or sub-domain, as a typical WordPress installation is set to run for a particular domain or subdomain.
2. Even if you are able to make it work, before every redirect WordPress will first load itself and then do the redirect and then load again when the redirected URL reaches the server. That's a slow process.

Instead do it in .htaccess. Like the following:

```html
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# custom rules for subdomain matching
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# default WordPress rules
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

This will redirect all sub.example.com to example.com/sub.

> Note: The above CODE will also redirect www.example.com to
>   example.com/www. If you don't want that, then modify the above #
>   custom rules for subdomain matching section to the following:

```html
# to redirect www.example.com/* to example.com/*
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]
# custom rules for subdomain matching
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule . http://example.com/%1 [R=301,L]
```

Read this doc. to learn more about apache [mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Also, make sure [mod_rewrite is enabled for .htaccess](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48362/how-to-enable-mod-rewrite-in-apache) in your server.

Comment: Hi Priyanka, and thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure I understand - there is no subdomain or other domain involved here, merely a sub-directory under the same domain. 
- WordPress is installed under http://example.com/wp/
- The website is running directly under http://example.com/ by tweaking the index.php 

I'm not sure how the solution applies to the issue. 
Thanks in advance for any clarification!